# Triangular waveform modelling of scatterplot

Tags: statistics, approximation, wave-equation

I have a scatter plot of Voltage vs. Time that looks like this:
[scatterplot of voltage vs time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkI9n.png). The points were collected with analog to digital conversion with a data logger sampling at a constant frequency.

It is assumed that these points would ideally make a triangular waveform, like this: [scatterplot of voltage with time with superimposed waveform sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcWRl.png). My question is this: **how do I find the average period of that waveform?** I couldn't find any good leads on Google.

I have had two thoughts on how to do this so far:

1. Mathematically find all the inflection points, where dV/dt = 0, like this: [inflection points sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHB1D.png). I am hoping there is some formula you can use to find this, I have no idea if it exists. Once I have the inflection points, the period is just the average change in time between them. Note that I have access to MatLab.
2. Estimate the frequency. Here is a more close-up picture of the graph that includes times: [graph with times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIWGt.png). Based on this graph, I can make a rough estimate of a period of 10 seconds. My problem with this method is that it has much more error than a mathematical approach, and takes a long time to do for multiple cycles.

Thanks for your help